# Cannot install npm package in a mounted directory

Tags: node.js, docker, npm, semantic-ui, docker-volume

My idea is to use docker container for building js and css assets separately from an app. I have code at the host machine and I'm trying to mount the directory with my code as volume to docker container. But in the Dockerfile when I do `RUN npm install sematic-ui --save` it doesn't change anything in the directory I'm trying to mount.

Is the mounted volume available at all at the building process or should I install npm packages only when I run image?

Also what is the best practice in my case?

EDIT:

I simplified the case to show an example. Here are my files.

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3'
services:
 web:
  build: .
  volumes:
    - ./vol:/root/test
```

Dockerfile

```
FROM debian:9
WORKDIR /root/test
RUN touch index.html
CMD /bin/sh
```

Then I do `docker-compose build`.
I expect to see the index.html in the `vol` directory on the host. Why this doesn't happen? As I noticed some docker images could change the host's filesystem during build. But I couldn't.

Comment: Post your whole Dockerfile please

Comment: @bluescores see my edit

Answer (score 0):

When you mount a volume, it replaces everything in the directory to which you are mounting it in the container. Whatever you have in `/root/test` will be replaced with your host `./vol` directory.

---

Also I'm not sure this would work anyway because when these lines happen:

```
WORKDIR /root/test
RUN touch index.html
```

the /root/test directory doesn't exist. I'm not sure where Docker is putting the index.html. Typically I will `RUN mkdir -p /root/test` to ensure the container path is explicitly created.

Comment: I put `RUN mkdir -p /root/test` before `WORKDIR /root/test`. Rebuilt and nothing happened (`vol` is still empty).

BTW, if I do `docker-compose up` then `docker-compose run web` and inside container when I create a file it appears in the `vol` directory. So it is working only after build.

Comment: See the first part of my answer. When you mount the volume in your docker-compose you're functionally erasing everything that exists at /root/test in the container up to that point. This would include the index.html file.

Comment: I think you're right in that. But still it's not possible to change the host files on the build stage. I decided to use `ENTRYPOINT` script to deal with that. That is how the things are going in the `mysql:5.7` image.